# Python manage classes in separate files

Tags: python, class, design-patterns, import

I have a project which uses the MVC pattern.

In folder "models" I have quite many classes, each class is now has its own file. But I feel like it's not convenient, because every time I need to use a class I have to import it separately. E.g. I have many of the followings in my app source:

```
from models.classX import classX
from models.classY import classY
```

If I want to import everything at once, something like `from models import *` I found that I can put all sorts of `import` in `models/__init__.py`. But is it the pythonic way to do it ? What is the convention ?

Comment: Please uses PEP8 casing so you can distinguish classes and modules! - `from models.classx import ClassX`

Answer (score 6):

Python is not java; please avoid the one-file-per-class pattern. If you can't change it, you can import all of them from a submodule of your `models` package:

```
# all.py: convenient import of all the needed classes
from models.classX import classX
from models.classY import classY
...
```

Then in your code you can write:

```
import my.package.models.all as models  # or from my.package.models.all import *
```

and proceed to use `models.classX`, `models.classY`, etc.

Comment: You can do the same from within `models/__init__.py`, then you just do `import my.package.models`.

Comment: @glglgl Then you lose the ability to import the `class...` modules individually—any import of anything from the package will load the whole bunch. If this tight coupling is desirable (or already present), then importing them in `__init__.py` is the way to go. But one would hope that the whole *point* of having so many modules is to be able to import them separately.

Comment: Any reason to avoid one-file-per-class pattern in python ? Is it much harder to read when putting everything in one models.py file ?

Comment: Well, I do not find it much harder, but probably it is just a matter of habits, namely how you use an IDE/editor.

Comment: In Python it's natural to group classes of related functionality. Then you can shared semi-private base classes, utility functions, and are easier to navigate. Automatically putting each class in a separate module seems a habit brought from languages that actually enforce this practice. If you find your code more readable that way, by all means go ahead, but that's not idiomatic Python.

Comment: If classes are related enough to live in the same module then they will probably share functions and variables. It usually makes sense to put those all in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

Most pythonic way is one that you're already using. You can alleviate importing by grouping your classes in modules. For example, in Django usually all application models are in a single file.

From python [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package):

> Although certain modules are designed to export only names that follow certain patterns when you use `import *`, it is still considered bad practise in production code.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should rename your classes and modules so that they don't match, and follow PEP8:

```
models/
    classx.py
        class ClassX
    classy.py
        class ClassY
```

Then, I'd got with this in `models/__init__.py`:

```
from models.classx import ClassX
from models.classy import ClassY
```

Meaning in your main code, you can do any one of:

```
from models import *
x = ClassX()
```

```
from models import ClassX
x = ClassX()
```

```
import models
x = models.ClassX()
```